# Illformed requirement error when installing gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to install any gem (sass as an example)

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
    Illformed requirement ["sass"]
```

[image]

I'm running Windows 10 Pro (not activated yet) so I was wondering if this could be a reason as to why this is happening? I've tried using the 32 bit version of Ruby 2.2.2 as well and it gives the same error. How do I fix this and what could be the reason I get it? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How are you installing.. Add command in your question

Comment: I'm installing Ruby using [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). I've tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions. I've tried installing using `gem update --system` as well as using the zip and `ruby setup.rb`